Disable/reset screen time passcode (account without AppleID)
I've got a Macbook Pro running MacOS 12.7.4 Monterey with two local accounts: user and admin, both without an AppleID.
The user account has a screen time passcode set that I forgot.
The official instructions say


Click Change Passcode, then click Forgot Passcode.
Enter the Apple ID and password you used to set up the Screen Time passcode. Forgotten your Apple ID password?


The window does not have a "forgot passcode" button, and I suspect this is because the account does not have an Apple ID.
Is there a way to reset the user's screen time passcode from the administrator account?
